# Building a web-app/service compatible application with QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I have been tasked with building an application that uses QGIS compatible geoprocessing libraries to do automated GIS tasks. The application should follow the criteria below:

- Coded in python
- Possible to run on a local machine
- Coded in such a way that future integration as a web app or web service should be smooth
- Complete with GUI features
- As efficient as possible. Meaning that the functionality should be called from python in as low level a way as possible. This is why I am a bit skeptical about the `iface` API.

I really have no idea where to start. Should I even be thinking in terms of QGIS or should I be looking at individual `geoprocessing`libraries such as GDAL or GRASS? Isn't QGIS just a platform with a mix of different geoprocessing tools? Should I be using `iface`?

Comment: You could use Qt to design the interface/widgets.

Comment: Is Qt compatible with a Web app type program such as something the Boundless web app plugin could spit out?

Comment: Most web apps are written in Java so no, not directly anyway. You might have some luck using Jython or QtJambi, but I'm not familiar with either I'm afraid